Software to simulate doing electrolysis with sodium in aqueous solution where one can see electron flow from battery/all redox
I am requesting a picture/simulation or software that can show me the electron flow of the battery's electron flow as well as the electron flow of the metal in reducing anything it reduces in aqueous electrolysis with two half-cells where the metal is more reactive than water or the aqueous solution and or hydrogen gas forms instead of reducing the highly reactive metal?
I'd like to know how the speed of metal reducing the aqueous solution or anything the metal reduces compares to current causing reduction of anything. Generally, what happens when you change the non-zero voltage of the battery up and down in magnitude in this case?

Take a look at LAMMPS software.

It would help to know exactly what accuracy you need, at what length scale and what time scale. With a few numbers and the Tafel equation you could get a good qualitative understanding, widely applicable, in a few pages of math.
